# How can I execute an apply-templates on all non-selected attributes within a xsl:copy?

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

Let's say I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@componentClassID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

How can I conclude the copy with an apply-templates statement that selects all attributes not specified in the previous apply-templates statements?

Would the following be correct?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='id' and name()!='name' and name()!='componentClassID']"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I execute an apply-templates on all non-selected elements within a xsl:copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308506/how-can-i-execute-an-apply-templates-on-all-non-selected-elements-within-a-xslc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the following be correct?
>
> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates select=
>  "@*[name()!='id' and name()!='name' and name()!='componentClassID']"/>
> ```

**Yes, but it seems too-long**. Also, it is recommended never to use the `!=` operator, because of its unintuitive semantics (behavior) when one of its arguments is a node-set.

**When there are *many* attribute names to be excluded, I'd rather write in the following style:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=
 "@*[not(contains('+id+name+componentClassID+', concat('+', name(), '+')))]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 of course you can use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@id, @name, @class)"/>
```

You can also reduce it to a single apply-templates:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@id, @name, @class, @* except (@id, @name, @class)"/>
```

If you're uncomfortable with the repetition you could use a sort:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
  <xsl:sort select="f:attOrder(.)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:function name="f:attOrder" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="attribute()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ix" select="index-of(("id", "name", "class"), local-name($a))"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="($ix, 1000)[1]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Or (this one works in 1.0 as well) you could use modes:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@componentClassID"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="remainder"/>

<xsl:template match="@id|@name|@componentClassID" mode="remainder"/>
```